# Given everything decays and falls apart, does anything matter forever?

Tags: meaning-of-life, imperfection

Given everything decays and falls apart, does anything matter ***forever***? It's an obvious question, but a no would be quietly sobering and arguably leave us with a variant on hedonism, seeing as what matters is just in the moment (however long the monent is).

If love doesn't exist, then love isn't important. If there are no rules, then abiding by them doesn't matter. My illness is only meaningful if it exists. The ontological status of things does seem to be linked to whether or not they mean anything.

Comment: One could argue that immortality could lead to the same variant hedonism. As an atheist, I have accepted that when I die that's it. Making the most out of my short time does not have to be about hedonism but it does redefine the notion of a "good" life and living in the moment.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks @IdiosyncraticSoul even the finest joys can be meaningless

Comment: this may be too opinion based as it is. apologies if so @IdiosyncraticSoul i wouldn't worry about it ha

Comment: Hasn't this non-sequitur cliche been repeated enough already? What does how anything is and whether it is reversible have to do with whether it matters?

Comment: is 'cliche' your new 'cliche'? i don't know, but if it's been answered then link to it?

Comment: why is it more of a cliche then "is the universe necessary", which has two or three new questions on? what about the 100s of questions about bayes that went nowhere @Conifold pretty funny that you target me for your poetic lol scorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question contains a number of important ambiguities. The phrase 'it matters' can be applied in the sense of meaning 'I think it matters and will continue to matter after I am gone'. In other words, you can anticipate long term consequences and make judgements about them even though they will not affect you, or anyone else potentially, when they arise. Given that, you can say that the inevitable decay itself certainly matters forever, because it will prevent a number of things that you consider to be important- such as the flourishing of civilisations.

Depending on how I read it, the question could also imply an unnecessary linkage between continued existence and consequences. People and objects can have consequences long after they have turned back to dust.

On the other hand, if you use the phrase 'it matters' to mean that it will continue to matter to someone, then clearly you could say that as the final decay of the Universe is approached, nothing will matter because there will be no sentient beings for things to matter to.

Comment: "People and objects can have consequences long after they have turned back to dust" yeah I guess you are right. We are still living in the shadow of many things that are now over